# Repeated block in homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I created a page that shows a carousel with the images of the categories, but Magento is replicating the same block below the footer. Why?

[image: HomePage with repeated block]

[image: Repeated block. Inspecting the element.]

Line for the block on HomePage:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="page/html" name="branches" output="toHtml" template="branches/list.phtml"></block>
<!-- others blocks -->
</reference>
```

Code of html page:

```
<div class="slider5">
<?php
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 3)
                ->addIsActiveFilter();

foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <div class="slide">
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrlPath(); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $category->getCategoryImage($this,100,100); ?>" alt="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>"/>
    </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<?php ?>       
</div>
```

Any idea?
Thanks!!

Comment: Are you echoing the block on your homepage template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your block xml from

```
<block type="page/html" name="branches" output="toHtml" template="branches/list.phtml"></block>
```

to

```
<block type="core/template" name="branches" template="branches/list.phtml" />
```